# GeneratorsNeeded error in SymPy using Sum with a constant polynomial

Tags: python, sympy

I'm getting the error

> sympy.polys.polyerrors.GeneratorsNeeded: can't initialize from 'dict' without generators

when I try to sum a zero polynomial.  The error occurs at the line

```
    g = k*Sum(f,(m,k,n)).doit()
```

Here `m` and `n` are symbols, and `k` is an int. The error occurs 
the first time through the loop, when `f` has been initialized to `Poly(0,m)`.  The script computes a sequence of polynomials.  If instead I initialize `f` to `Poly(m,m)` the script runs to completion.  If I try `Poly(1,m)` I get the same error as before.

How can I define a constant polynomial so that my script will execute properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Sum` passes `doit()` to the object it is trying to sum, which is where the error occurs. So, a minimal example is

```
x = symbols('x')
f = Poly(0, x)
f.doit()  #  GeneratorsNeeded: can't initialize from 'dict' without generators
```

Looks like a bug, an edge case not being addressed correctly. But there is a workaround: pass an *expression* to Sum (which is what it expects anyway), not a Poly object. A Poly is turned into an expression with `as_expr()`.

```
f = Poly(0, m)
Sum(f.as_expr(), (m, 0, n)).doit()   #  0
```